# CSS3 only transition while hovered

Tags: html, css

I have an element with `transition: margin-left 0.7s;` on it.

The transition works fine, but it also animates on zoom. Is there any way to stop this?

Examples using `width` instead of `margin-left`:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7py46d3L/

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    transition: width 0.7s;
    width: 5vw;
    height: 10px;
}
div:hover {
    width: 10vw
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `width:5vw;` and make width as in `PX` or in `%`

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    transition: width 0.7s;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
}
div:hover {
    width: 10vw
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7py46d3L/1/)

Comment: This works, so I thank you, and most likely will accept you as the answer, but I'm going to leave this question open for a while to see if I can get any "better" -- more leniant answers. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... Actually, this isn't quite working for my needs. May explain later.

Comment: @Quelklef If this answer is correct for your question in it's current state; accept it. If your actual usercase is different from your question in it's current state, either edit your question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

**Understanding sizing in CSS**

---

**There are two types of measurement units:**

1. **relative lengths:**
   Relative length units specify a length relative to another length. The relative units are: **em, ex, ch, rem, vw, vh, vmin, vmax**. They are mainly useful when the output media has dynamic size like responsive layout for mobile device, laptop.
2. **absolute lengths:** these are fixed in relation to each other and anchored to some physical measurement. The absolute units are: **px, mm, cm, in, pt, pc**.They are mainly useful when the output environment is known.

> **so in your example if you give width:5[any absolute lengths or in]then > it will work**